# Ghost Strand Appears after Rendering?

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, particles, hair

I keep having this problem with a strand of hair that appears after rendering. I cannot, for the life of me find whatever particle is causing this.

I've tried hitting the A key highlighting them and translating on all axis. I've tried deleting all the particles that occur on that side of the head. And I've turned down, then off the children and have also adjusted the number of parent strands to no avail.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem, or do I just have a ghost strand? I'm am nowhere finished with this hair mesh, so, if I have to, I don't mind deleting it and starting all over, but I'd rather try to solve this problem for future reference.

Thanks, Blender Community.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I've uploaded a simplified here if anyone wants to check it out: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=3701" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/3701/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you have *Subsurf modifier* **before** Hair, but forgot to enable *Use modifier stack* in Particle System. Moreover you hide Subsurf from viewport render, thus problem remains only in final render.

I assume you have to undo all Hair editing and enable *Use modifier stack*, then comb Hair from the start. Also your levels for Subsurf modifier are different for final render and viewport. This can cause another problems in the future.

Comment: Wow. Thanks so much, Serge L. I forgot all about the stack, but following your instructions, the problem is fixed. Thanks again.